# (Node.JS) NodeRequire does not succeed/find module when launching Microsoft Edge Instance

Tags: node.js, microsoft-edge, npm-live-server

For starters, I am a complete novice when it comes to web development, so I apologize first for likely lacking appropriate information. Any discussion will be helpful so I can get a better idea of how Node.JS and live-server work.

I am attempting to debug a app.js file I wrote, with the following steps:

1. In VSCode; deploying to live-server localhost, port 5500.
2. Launching Microsoft Edge on localhost, port 5500.

I can successfully hit my breakpoints in the (app).js file, provided below (as one line). On Edge, it exits unsuccessfully on this line:

`var express = require('express');`

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get more information on what's causing the failure. Some additional information of my own:

1. I did `npm install express` and can find the `express` folder in my `node_modules`, but when hovering over the `require` function, I see a different path to my Local AppData folder. I also tried `require('../node_modules/express/index')` directly, but that also exited unsuccessfully.
2. The file does run succesfully if I call it directly with `node app.js`, which confuses me what the difference between this function and what Edge does.

I'm sure there's something I neglected to mention, so please let me know!

I tried using `NodeRequire` in Node.JS while launching to Microsoft Edge. I was expecting this to work like when I called it directly with `node app.js`, but it instead exited unsuccessfully.

Comment: You cannot run the line of code `var express = require('express');` in Edge.  That line of code requires nodejs for the Javascript environment and will not run in any browser.

Comment: Good to know! Guess I'll have to check out some other options then. Thank you!